# Calling setContextProperty() with a QList<MyObject*>

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I based my code on the examples found in the [documentation of Qt Quick 2.0](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model) to provide data to a `ListModel` in my QML dynamically from C++.

**MyModel.h**:

```
class MyObject: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)

  public:
    MyObject(QObject *parent=0);
    ~MyObject();

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    QString deviceName;

  Q_SIGNALS:
    void nameChanged();
};
```

**QML file**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListView {
    width: 100; height: 100

    model: myModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: 25
        width: 100
        Text { text: name }
    }
}
```

In my **Main.cpp** I now create a `QList<QObject *>` that I fill with some instances of `MyModel` and it works:

```
QList<QObject *> listElems;
listElems.append(new MyModel());
listElems.append(new MyModel());

QQmlContext *ctxt = view->rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel",QVariant::fromValue(listElems));
```

But if instead of using a `QList<QObject *>` I use a `QList<MyObject *>` then I get errors when loading the QML indicating that the property name is not defined:

> qrc:view.qml:10: ReferenceError: name is not defined

I tried using `qRegisterMetaType<T>()` and  `qmlRegisterType<T>()` without success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the QML source (or part of it) along with the exact error? Are you sure "audioInputDeviceInfoView" is defined in your QML? I don't think you need to use qRegisterMetaType.

Comment: @ChrisR I added the QML and the error. If you have the qt5 examples installed you can try the one in "examples/quick/models/objectlistmodel". If you replace in Main.cpp the QList<QObject*> by QList<DataObject*> you'll get the same error

Comment: I'm no specialist and having issues with Qt/QML as well. Could one of the two following links help (even if designed for Qt4.8 instead of 5.0, it should mostly work): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativemodels.html#exposing-c-data-models-to-qml http://cdumez.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-use-c-list-model-in-qml.html

Comment: @ChrisR > I've read these ones and almost everything I could find about this. As a matter of fact, for now I moved to the QAbstractListModel method which works. But I wanted to understand why providing a specialized QList does not work.

Comment: Is it possible that there is some sort of conflict having the read function be the same name as your property?

Comment: @Deadron : I tried changing the name just in case but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your MyModel class and the QML side identical, just change the following part:

```
#include <qqml.h>

qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyModel>("MyModel", 1, 0, "MyModel", "Instanciated C++ side !");

QVariantList listElems;
listElems.append(QVariant::fromValue(new MyModel()));
listElems.append(QVariant::fromValue(new MyModel()));
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel",QVariant::fromValue(listElems));
```

And of course ' import MyModel 1.0 ' in the QML.

And it should work !

Comment: It only partially works: with your solution `name` is still undefined, I need to access it through `model.modelData.name`. And it is more complicated than just using a `QList<QObject*>`.
My question is why it does not work with a `QList<MyObject *>`

Comment: Just use modelData.name, you have no other choice with a QML ListView or Repeater, you must use modelData when using a QObjectList based model.

Comment: Btw, it's a good practice to always specify 'modelData.' or 'model.' before the property name, in order to avoid complexe naming/scoping resolution for the QML engine, and avoid also definition conflicts.

Comment: That's not what the example "examples/quick/models/objectlistmodel" shows. With my current example I don't need to use `model.modelData` and it works. Why shouldn't it work?

I understand that it can be viewed as a good practice. But my main question is to understand why it works with a `QList<QObject*>` and not with `QList<MyObject *>`

Comment: Examples may be outdated or bordercase, from my experience, QVariantList + modelData is the only way to go without a headache or without warming up the big QAbstractListModel machinery...

Comment: Ok. I understand your answer that in the end it would be better to use a `QVariantList`. I'm just trying to understand how types are shared between C++ and QML here and what happens with my `QList`. But thanks for taking a look!